# Meteor.connection._lastSessionId is undefined in onCreated

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

So I have this code guys

```
Template.mainLayout.onCreated(function () { //HERE
  console.log("mainLayout created");
  var context = FlowRouter.current();
  // use context to access the URL state
  console.log(context);
  var visitedOne = context.path;

  //getting the connID

  var clientIp = headers.getClientIP(); // no need for this anymore
  var clientConnId = Meteor.connection._lastSessionId; // HERE
  console.log(clientIp);
  console.log(clientConnId); //HERE
  // console.log(Meteor.connection._lastSessionId);



  Meteor.call("updateHistory", {clientIp,clientConnId,visitedOne}, function(error, result){
   if(error){
     console.log("error", error);
 });
   if(result){

   }
  });//Meteor.call
});
```

My problems are marked by the comments `//HERE`

`Meteor.connection._lastSessionId` returns undefined at onCreated event. However if I try to get on click event it works just fine. Why is this caused, what's a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to log the session ID before the connection has received it. For example, wrap your call in a `setTimeout`:

```
...
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(Meteor.connection._lastSessionId);
}, 500);
...
```

You might have to tweak the timeout value a bit, but it will be logged. Using `setTimeout` in this fashion really isn't that reliable though, as the amount of time it takes for the session ID to get set can vary. You'll likely want to look into setting up some kind of simple polling to continuously check for the session ID, until it's set.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `_lastSessionId` isn't yet available on the client when the template is originally created (it's probably the first template rendered in your app). However there is no need to get this on the client since you're calling a server method anyway, just use the variable directly there where it will already exist!

So simplify:

```
Meteor.call("updateHistory", {clientIp,clientConnId,visitedOne}, callback)
```

to:

```
Meteor.call("updateHistory", visitedOne, callback)
```

and get the clientIp (if necessary) and use `this.connection.id` on the server.